# Why can't I create an AMI with ephemeral storage?

Tags: amazon-ec2, bamboo

I am building a Bamboo CI server on EC2. I start by launching a default image from within Bamboo OnDemand, modifying it as required and creating an S3-backed AMI from it.

That part works fine, however `/home/bamboo` is on ephemeral storage:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-68-55-19 ~]$ mount
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime)
/dev/xvdb on /media/ephemeral0 type ext3 (rw)
/media/ephemeral0/home on /home type none (rw,bind)
```

So `/home` is not included in the AMI. And when the agent tries to start on boot there is no `/home/bamboo`.

What's the best way to handle this? Copy the 42mb to somewhere else and retake the snapshot... then how would I restore the correct directory locations when the instance boots?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Here's my question on the Atlassian answers forum: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/277207/custom-ami-problems-elastic-agent-doesn-t-start-and-ssh-fails